# Getting QScrollArea to resize its child widget immediately

Tags: qt, qscrollarea

I have a QScrollArea (we'll call it myContainer) that contains and scrolls a child view (we'll call it myChildWidget). All works almost fine - when I change the height of myChildWidget dynamically in response to something, if the height exceeds that of myContainer (the QScrollArea), a vertical scroll bar pops into view, effectively narrowing myChildWidget since I've set it to resize its child using:

```
myContainer->setWidgetResizable(true);
```

The problem is that myChildWidget is not actually resized until later, rather than right when I set its new height or try resizing myContainer, so I can't do certain things depending on its new width without subclassing and putting in a whole bunch of extra code. Surely there's something I can call to get the QScrollArea to auto-resize its child right away, right? I can use:

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

but the problem with that is that it causes the widgets to flash and redraw when I'm not done setting things up. I've tried update(), updateGeometry(), and adjustSize(), both on the container and its child, and none work. Anything I'm missing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Will this (size hint) work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685494/get-size-of-qscrollarea-viewport-before-showing Sometimes the size hint for the content is enough and sometimes you can just make it a bit more explicit.

Comment: Adding myChildWidget->setMinimumSize(myChildWidget->sizeHint()); and myChildWidget->adjustSize(); as in that link seems to just make the scroll bar and scroll functionality of the parent QScrollArea just go away completely, unfortunately.

Comment: You can try to subclass the child widget and implement http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop because the existing implementation is probably returning something not usable. Then try with and without calling setMinimumSize.

Comment: When sub-classing `QAbstractScrollArea`, I noticed that certain things (like e.g. forcing an update) did not work. Then I realized that such things have to be applied to the `QAbstractScrollArea::viewport()`. So, this might be worth a consideration.